# Align text on far left of graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, text, alignment

I'm trying to figure out how to align text with the far left of a graph in matplotlib. I can accomplish this by hard coding the value (in the example below x=-.98), however this takes a lot of trial and error.

Is there away to return the coordinates of the figure border (not the graph border) or to set the text to start at the far left of the figure?

```
# matplotlib example of text align
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# x and y axis data
y_axis_labels = ['y-label-1','y-label-2','y-label-3','y-label-4']
x_axis_labels = [1,2,3,4]

# create horizontal bar plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.barh(y_axis_labels, x_axis_labels)

# Align the text with the far left of the y_axis labels
plt.text(x=-.98,y=4, s='start at far left', color='red')

plt.show()
```

[Link to example image (I want the red text to align with blue line)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4sMF1.png)

Comment: try this `plt.title('haha', x=-0.14049, y=0.98)` ?

Answer (score -1):

Replace

```
plt.text(x=-.98,y=4, s='start at far left', color='red')
```

with

```
ax.set_title('start at far left',loc='right',color='red' )
```

Comment: this is not what he need

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This places the text on the left of the graph, but not the fart left of the figure. In a horizontal bar chart it aligns it with the edge of the bars rather than the edge of the y-axis labels.